# deploying a django project to Heroku: ImproperlyConfigured error; STATIC_ROOT setting

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

Thank you for look at here!
I met a problem when I want to deploy a Django project to Heruko.

Here is the error information.

```
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --    noinput'
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

When I try:

```
'$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'
```

I got:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

Here is my settings(the same as https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets):

```
# Heroku settings
if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    # let request.is_secure() admit X-Forwarded-Proto header
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    # support all host header
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
    )
```

I have seen the similar questions on stack overflow, but they did not work for me.
Any guide could be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: you have a typo `manange.py` ?

Comment: sorry，I will try again. Thank you for remaining.

Comment: But why have you put it inside that `os.getcwd() == '/app'` guard? That will never be true in development, do you have reason to think it it is true on Heroku? Even if it is, there are much better ways of determining which environment you are running in.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Well, actually I am a beginner of learning programming. I just followed a book that told me to do so. I deleted the if statement, then it worked. Thank you very much!! If you have time to explain more, it could not be more good.